# Firebase Storage exception

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

My code was working perfectly, but today i was getting this exception, can anyone help?Log is attached
Thanks

```
10-03 13:33:50.141 15352-17764/com.shahzain.ada E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
                                                                              An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.


Code: -13000 HttpResult: 200
10-03 13:33:50.141 15352-17764/com.shahzain.ada E/StorageException: the maximum allowed buffer size was exceeded.
                                                                          java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: the maximum allowed buffer size was exceeded.
                                                                              at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference$5.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
                                                                              at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                              at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$8.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
10-03 13:33:50.141 15352-17764/com.shahzain.ada E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
                                                                          An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
                                                                           Code: -13000 HttpResult: 200
10-03 13:33:50.141 15352-17764/com.shahzian.ada E/StorageException: the maximum allowed buffer size was exceeded.
                                                                          java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: the maximum allowed buffer size was exceeded.
                                                                              at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference$5.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
                                                                              at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                              at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$8.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

here is code, which is for downloading content from firebase storage

```
final long ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;
islandRef.getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
        // Data for "images/island.jpg" is returns, use this as needed
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Handle any errors
    }
});
```

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('why isn't this code working?') must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: I was unable to figure out exact part of code, I know it is in firebase storage, but it was working for some videos and throwing exception for some videos, later I have answered my question thanks.

Comment: btw, Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen you helped me alot in firebase related questions :)

Comment: Good to hear that you found the cause of the problem!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have fixed above problem by exceeding size in code first size was 1mb , later I increased it to 5mb.

```
final long ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;
```

change this to larger size like

```
final long ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024 *5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check that google play services are up to date.If not update it. If it is up to date clear the cache memory of google play services.

Answer (score -2):

I think the best solution is use another download method. Because it must load the entire contents of your file into memory. If you request a file larger than your app's available memory, your app will crash.

You should use download Data via URL:

```
storageRef.child("users/me/profile.png").
getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            // Got the download URL for 'users/me/profile.png'
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            // Handle any errors
        }
    });
```

And in your `imageview`, you use `Glide` to show it:

```
Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
 .load(mFirebaseUser.getPhotoUrl())
 .into(mYourImageView);`
```